# Can't change SQL to have an id as primary key(AI) rather than username

Tags: php, mysql, sql, registration

I recently started using Jpmaster77's Login Script, and it has shown to be very great. However, now I am trying to experiment with it. I am trying to create a new table at the beginning of the row named "id" that has a primary key or AI, rather than the table username. To my knowledge, only one table can have a primary key or AI, but yet when I try to create this "id" table, the script becomes unable to register on. I don't get an ACTUAL error, but I get this message after attempting to log in "

We're sorry, but an error has occurred and your registration for the username (username trying to register with here), could not be completed.
Please try again at a later time."

This happens when I try to change this

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 username varchar(30) primary key,
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null
);
```

to this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 username varchar(30),
 password varchar(32),
 userid varchar(32),
 userlevel tinyint(1) unsigned not null,
 email varchar(50),
 timestamp int(11) unsigned not null
);
```

From receiving this error, I believe it has something to do with my code rather than SQL. I have 3 pages that affect the registration, register.php, process.php, and session.php
I will post a link to all 3 so anyone can see for themselves "http://pastebin.com/5efyZdgF" (please forget the error, I mispelled register.php at the beginning)

If anyone can help, i'd be very thankful since I haven't had the chance to make this work. I do understand PHP very well, so If anyone could at least point out my error I can most likely correct it from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the A_I is required to be an integer (int)

This is because the integer increases based on the previous table.. If this is a `varchar` or otherwise (not asscoiated with a number) How is a letter going to increase in value based on the previous? it can't..

The AI is used to minimize duplicate rows within your table

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with MySQL so I took a quick glance at the docs.  It looks like the syntax is similar to redbrick, which I do work with.

```
create table myTable (
myTableId int not null auto_increment
, more fields
, constraint myTablePk primary key (myTableId)
```